# Start loginActivity in the loginActivity itself when there is Wi-Fi connection

Tags: android, android-layout

I am pretty much new to Android application. My application is working by reading the data from SQLite Database when there is no Wi-Fi connection. Entry point to the application is Login screen.

When there is no Wi-Fi connection and no cache, we are popping up a message to setup Wi-Fi connection. Once they setup Wi-Fi, then we need to start to get the initial configuration to show some data in Login screen from server.

The problem is I have no idea how to restart the application to get the data from server once we setup Wi-Fi.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given us much to go on, so the best I can do is give you some high level advice. All you need to do is once you're done setting up the wifi, then just launch another Intent that starts your login activity. So once your wifi setup is done, do something like the following:

```
Intent loginActivity = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(loginActivity);
```

This assumes that you're calling from a class which extends `Context` and the name of your login activity class is `LoginActivity`.

Comment: As a side-note: you should listen for the Wifi state change being broadcast. So when you receive the broadcast saying that Wifi has changed to "on" launch the login activity.

Comment: if you provide some sample code to do this, that will be a great help. thanks

Comment: I added some code to my answer. But without knowing more about your program, I can't give you anything more.

Comment: i added a reload button in loginactivity  and used the same to code when they click the reload button to get intial configuration. but that didn't work. i need to resume this activity when they come back to this login screen.

Comment: i can't add anothor activity to launch this activity. this is the first screen (home page) when the user turn on the android tablet.

Comment: Once they turn on the wifi connection, we are rebooting the tablet and the problem is this application is triggered before the wifi is tunred on even though they did the wifi setup.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no, wifi give him alert dialogs and
u should use `startActivityForResult()`
and

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data)
```

here are some tutorials to get u startred   :[nice example](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Android-Activity-startActivityForResult-387002)

[developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment on @Kurtis's answer here is a quick and dirty piece of sample code you can use to listen for Wifi state changes...

```
public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Register for Wifi state changes.
    this.registerReceiver(wifiChangedReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
}

// BroadcastReceiver that will get notified when the Wifi state changes.
private BroadcastReceiver wifiChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        int extraWifiState = arg1.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        // No need to listen for all the states, but it might be interesting
        // at a later point ;)
        switch (extraWifiState) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            showToast("Wifi disabled...");
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
            showToast("Wifi disabling...");
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            showToast("Wifi enabled...");
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            showToast("Wifi enabling...");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

// Instead of showing a toast, you could launch a new activity.
private void showToast(String action) {
    Toast.makeText(this, action, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

// When leaving the activity that has registered for a broadcast, remember
// to unregister the broadcast or you'll get an exception at some point.
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    this.unregisterReceiver(wifiChangedReceiver);
    }
}
```

Some might argue that it would be better to move the BroadcastReceiver into a class of its own . That can be accomplished by creating your own class and extending the class by BroadcastReceiver.

Hope this helps ;-)